# Insert multiple rows in sql

Tags: php, sql, insert

Can someone tell me why this query is wrong?

```
$tbl_name = "Attributes";
$pieces = //some array 
//other variables... blah blah blah

$query = "INSERT INTO $tbl_name (Word, What, When) VALUES";
foreach($pieces as $word){
    $query .= "('$word', '$What', '$When'),";
}

$query = substr($query, 0, -1);  //to remove the last comma

mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

If you can tell, I am trying to insert multiple rows with a single query. When I try and run it, I get hit with a syntax error, but I am 99.9999% sure there are no spelling mistakes. Am I doing something wrong by trying to insert multiple rows at once like this?

Comment: `WHEN` is a reserved word in mySQL. Wrap the column name in backticks  or use a different column name

Comment: You're doing something wrong by not using bound parameters or (less preferable) sanitizing strings. It looks OK, print the SQL statement out & try it in your SQL tool to see what's wrong.

Comment: Good god. So simple a mistake. You saved me hours of work.

Comment: **By building SQL statements with outside variables, you are leaving yourself wide open to SQL injection attacks.**  Also, any input data with single quotes in it, like a name of "O'Malley", will blow up your SQL query. Please learn about using parametrized queries, preferably with the PDO module, to protect your web app.  http://bobby-tables.com/php has examples to get you started, and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) has many examples in detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**when** is a reserved word either wrap it in  `` or use another. List of MySQL reserved words: 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: Thank you!!!!!! It is funny to think that I used the variable "When" as an example by pure chance, potentially saving hours more work.

Comment: its a good thing to do once, you remember never to do it again!

Answer (score 0):

is it possible that at some point in your $word,$what,$when you have a ' that is unsacaped ? or some mysql injection ?

if yes i would try using mysql_real_escape_string http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php